# Make a slow drifting motion for a physics group phaser.js

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

So I have a physics group, with a very low velocity like `child.setVelocity(1, 10);`

It's fine if this groups children speed up from a faster group collision, but I would like them to be very slow, basically unaffected by gravity but still moving, not speeding up by falling down, is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn of the gravity of one gameobject with the fucntion `gameobject.setAllowGravity(false)`
[link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body.html#setAllowGravity__anchor).

Or if you are using it in a physics group, you can use the property `allowGravity` and set it to `false`.
[link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Types.Physics.Arcade.html#.PhysicsGroupConfig)